# How can I get pylint to respect file-level ignores after the shebang line?

Tags: python, pylint

I'm working on a file that is *required* to have permissions `755`, and a shebang line. It also shouldn't have a `coding` line.

The file starts like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# pylint: disable=superfluous-parens,no-encoding-in-file,file-perms,incompatible-py3-code

...  # more code here
```

However, pylint complains about this:

```
[E0599(file-perms), ]
[W9903(no-encoding-in-file), ]
```

If I swap the order of the first to lines, hooray, it works!

But... then the shebang line doesn't.

Is there a way to tell pylint to respect my wishes about this file, without globally ignoring those things for every file in the project?

Comment: Are there files you *do* want pylint to warn about permissions or encodings? You could put those two controls in a configuration file, rather than in the script itself.

Comment: Yeah, literally all the rest of them. This is the only exception. It's weird that pylint doesn't just ignore the `#!` line if it's the beginning of the file because that's so extraordinarily *well known*. Even Python docstrings and `__future__` imports are cool with skipping the shebang lines!